# NSUserDefaults - Saving and retrieving "High Scores"

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am just learning to program and doing some SWIFT tutorials. I have done as much research as I could but seem to be missing some critical aspect. I have a simple game and when a player dies I want to check their score against the previously saved high. If it's higher it's to save the new score.

On a title screen the highest score is displayed.

Here is the current code I am using;

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")

    if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

The problem I cannot solve is simply how to print the highscore! I tried using;

```
hiScoreText.text = "Hi Score :  \(highscore)"
```

but as I guessed that isn't correct. What variable do I use or how do I "read" the highscore that has been saved?

Any advice for a new guy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont need synchronize() `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to save retrieved highs score to the variable:

```
let highscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

Comment: Thank you greatly. Again, a clear concise answer to my silly oversight... and again all in such a fast response time. Really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the result of `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")` inside a variable that you print.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Not only was it the solution I needed, but literally within a few minutes of me posting. Your help with this is very much appreciated.